# Problemas con editores de codigo

Tags: javascript, vscode, brackets

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y comence usando brackets para seguir los tutoriales, pero cuando sigo los pasos me muestra errores al parecer de sintaxis que me dejan el código roto.
Luego uso el mismo código en visual studio code y si lo lee perfectamente. Que podría ser?

Comment: Deberías agregar que errores obtienes

Comment: ... y una muestra pequeña del código con el problema.

Comment: Los editores vienen con algun tipo de chequeador de codigo (como ESLint) y cada uno configurado con reglas distintas, esto puede producir que distintos editores lancen distintos comentarios (mayormente advertencias de formato, noerrores). Si usas la misma configuracion `.eslintrc.json` deberia tener un resultado igual.